# Lost Executor trying to load Graph using Spark/GraphX in Yarn/hdfs Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, spark-graphx

I try to run a Spark/Graphx program written in Scala on YARN cluster with hdfs. The cluster has 16 nodes with 16GB RAM and 2TB HD each. All I want is to load an 3.29GB undirected Graph (called orkutUndirected.txt) using edgeListFile function, provided by GraphX library:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import java.io._
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

import scala.util.control.Breaks._
import scala.math._


object MyApp {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     // Create spark configuration and spark context
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My App")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val edgeFile = "hdfs://master-bigdata:8020/user/sparklab/orkutUndirected.txt" 
      // Load the edges as a graph
     val graph =GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,edgeFile,false,1,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
   }
}
```

I start the run using the following spark-submit in command line:

```
nohup spark-submit --master yarn --executor-memory 7g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2 ./target/scala-2.10/myapp_2.10-1.0.jar &
```

I tried different sizes of --executor-memory but no luck!!
After a few minutes I can see the following inside nohup.out:

```
16/02/24 23:45:25 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on node12-bigdata:     Executor heartbeat timed out after 160351 ms
16/02/24 23:45:29 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on node12-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:04:08 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on node13-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:18:05 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on node06-bigdata:     Executor heartbeat timed out after 129723 ms
16/02/25 00:18:07 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on node06-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:21:52 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on node16-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:41:29 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on node03-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:44:52 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 5 on node16-bigdata:     remote Rpc client disassociated
16/02/25 00:44:52 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most     recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, node16-bigdata):
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 lost)
Driver stacktrace:
at     org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
```

...
...

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what types of objects you are creating from the raw text file, 3.9GB of raw data can easily exceed the working memory of this cluster, causing large GC pauses and lost executors.  In addition to the overhead that comes with wrapping data in Java objects, there is additional overhead that comes with GraphX on top of RDDs.  [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) or [Ganglia](http://ganglia.info/) are good tools for debugging these memory related issues.  Also, see [Tuning Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html) for tips on how to keep your graph lean.

Another possibility is that the data was not partitioned optimally, causing some tasks stall.  See the Spark UI stage information and make sure that each task is working on evenly distributed data.  If it is not evenly distributed, you should repartition your data.  I found the [Cloudera Blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) on this subject useful.